# Access to variables inside EJS

Tags: javascript, sails.js, ejs

I want to use the objects I pass from `map.js` to `map.ejs`. In my request, I fetch the objects:

```
module.exports = async function(req, res) {
    var myObjects = await new Promise(resolve => {
        // resolve with objects
    });

    res.view('pages/map/home', {
        myObjects
    })
};
```

How can I access my objects in my .ejs file? I would like to loop through them to add them on the map, however, this doesn't print anything. It actually creates errors on the page. Part of map.ejs

```
<div id="mapid"></div>
<script>
// set up map
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([45.4735629, 9.1771209], 13);
// ...
// add markers on map using fetched objects
var myObjects = <%- myObjects %>
myObjects.forEach(f => {
    var marker = L.marker([f.latitude, f.longitude]).addTo(mymap); 
}
</script>
```

I get `Unexpected identifier` on myObjects in .ejs. Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: EJS exists to, with JS-based logic support, inject plain text into other plain text: you can't template  in a true JS object and expect that to work as assignment. Did you mean `res.view(..., { objects: JSON.stringify(myObjects) })`?

Comment: Can I `stringify` and then `parse` it back again in the EJS? Otherwise I'm not sure how I'd be able to use the data and access the object properties (latitude, ecc). @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: @Cesare you are approaching this wrong. Render the view and call a JSON API route on you site to render the `myObjects` as JSON. This would also allow you to deal with caching differently between view and data.

Comment: @Bibberty Sorry, I don't understand how I would call a JSON API to render the objects as JSON. I'm very new to this. Any pointers to examples?

Comment: @Cesare I added a working example to the end of the answer on Repl. I think it just helps to wrap up how it all comes together.

Comment: as for "parse it back": why would you parse it back? Remember: your EJS result _is text_, so there's nothing to "parse", the whole point is to take a JS object, which is very much not text, and turn it into text so that you can put it in your template. E.g. if in Node you have `data = { x: 'test' };` then you want to template in `view(..., {data: JSON.stringify(data)})` so that in the template you can say `const data = <%- data %>;`. Because after templating, that will now read `const data = { "x": "test" };`. The crucial piece is that you use EJS to generate _text inside other text_

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. My initial thought would be: if it's text, how would you iterate through it? I'm not sure if you can iterate over strings. I need iteration to create the markers one by one.

Comment: that's the thing: given what youre doing here, you're not "iterating", you're _generating_ - specifically, you're generating the _text_ of the javascript that the browser is going to have to execute, so what you want is to generate the text representation of your JS object, in a way that the browser will be able to read it in immediately. That's JSON. Of course, using a separate API call for that (as explained by Bibberty) is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave you `map` route to render the view `map.ejs`
This will send the HTML to the client.

So you view route might look like this:

```js
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('home', {})
});
```

Add a `route` for return map points e.g. `[site]/maps/getMapPoints/:location`

From that route simply respond with `JSON`.

Here is an example of an `API Route`

```js
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  geoLocate(req.ip).then(json => {
    res.json(json);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Now in the client `HTML` that was rendered by you `map.ejs` you will need to consume this. We will use this [REST Test Site](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

```js
// When the DOM has loaded.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    // Lets build out the HTML
    document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = `
      <div id="${json.id}"><h3>${json.title} - ${(json.completed) ? 'Complete' : 'Pending'}</h3></div>
    `;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Finally here is a working example of the seperation: [Sample Site](https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/TrustyCooperativeFibonacci)